# Logical Volume Resize fails with insufficient free space but PV and VG has free PE

Tags: debian, lvm, luks

So i would like to extend a logical volume but i run into some error.

The lvextend function tells me it cannot allocate space because there is no free space on the pv, but there is.

Something i am missing here?

```
sudo lvextend -L 80G /dev/mapper/ncvps--vg-data
Insufficient free space: 7680 extents needed, but only 0 available

sudo pvdisplay -m

--- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt
  VG Name               ncvps-vg
  PV Size               749.76 GiB / not usable 3.00 MiB
  Allocatable           NO
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              191937
  Free PE               168913
  Allocated PE          23024
  PV UUID               XOvj5D-ClTq-gfsw-F59L-aIqN-1tdt-OMGYrI

  --- Physical Segments ---
  Physical extent 0 to 7151:
    Logical volume  /dev/ncvps-vg/root
    Logical extents 0 to 7151
  Physical extent 7152 to 9199:
    Logical volume  /dev/ncvps-vg/swap_1
    Logical extents 0 to 2047
  Physical extent 9200 to 10223:
    Logical volume  /dev/ncvps-vg/home
    Logical extents 0 to 1023
  Physical extent 10224 to 23023:
    Logical volume  /dev/ncvps-vg/data
    Logical extents 0 to 12799
  Physical extent 23024 to 191936:
    FREE

additional information:

sudo vgdisplay -vv
      Setting activation/monitoring to 1
      Setting global/locking_type to 1
      Setting global/wait_for_locks to 1
      File-based locking selected.
      Setting global/prioritise_write_locks to 1
      Setting global/locking_dir to /run/lock/lvm
      Setting global/use_lvmlockd to 0
      Setting response to OK
      Setting token to filter:3239235440
      Setting daemon_pid to 608
      Setting response to OK
      Setting global_disable to 0
      Setting response to OK
      Setting response to OK
      Setting response to OK
      Setting name to ncvps-vg
      report/output_format not found in config: defaulting to basic
      log/report_command_log not found in config: defaulting to 0
      Processing VG ncvps-vg H0caAG-WH7t-SNWH-QxUg-4T2R-jW0F-fi6RW8
      Locking /run/lock/lvm/V_ncvps-vg RB
      Reading VG ncvps-vg H0caAGWH7tSNWHQxUg4T2RjW0Ffi6RW8
      Setting response to OK
      Setting response to OK
      Setting response to OK
      Setting name to ncvps-vg
      Setting metadata/format to lvm2
      Setting id to XOvj5D-ClTq-gfsw-F59L-aIqN-1tdt-OMGYrI
      Setting format to lvm2
      Setting device to 65024
      Setting dev_size to 1572354048
      Setting label_sector to 1
      Setting ext_flags to 1
      Setting ext_version to 2
      Setting size to 1044480
      Setting start to 4096
      Setting ignore to 0
      Setting response to OK
      Setting response to OK
      Setting response to OK
      /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt: size is 1572356096 sectors
      Process single VG ncvps-vg
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               ncvps-vg
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  12
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                4
  Open LV               3
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               749.75 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              191937
  Alloc PE / Size       23024 / 89.94 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       168913 / 659.82 GiB
  VG UUID               H0caAG-WH7t-SNWH-QxUg-4T2R-jW0F-fi6RW8

      Adding ncvps-vg/root to the list of LVs to be processed.
      Adding ncvps-vg/swap_1 to the list of LVs to be processed.
      Adding ncvps-vg/home to the list of LVs to be processed.
      Adding ncvps-vg/data to the list of LVs to be processed.
      Processing LV root in VG ncvps-vg.
  --- Logical volume ---
      global/lvdisplay_shows_full_device_path not found in config: defaulting to 0
  LV Path                /dev/ncvps-vg/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                ncvps-vg
  LV UUID                eNXazT-yprW-I2rq-K8hd-bGiy-e0Ur-XIBfEz
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ncvps, 2018-12-13 23:51:02 +0100
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                27.94 GiB
  Current LE             7152
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           254:1

      Processing LV swap_1 in VG ncvps-vg.
  --- Logical volume ---
      global/lvdisplay_shows_full_device_path not found in config: defaulting to 0
  LV Path                /dev/ncvps-vg/swap_1
  LV Name                swap_1
  VG Name                ncvps-vg
  LV UUID                MKjhK4-vgMY-4ajM-twQV-fDs6-ApOl-Lifkjz
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ncvps, 2018-12-13 23:51:02 +0100
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                8.00 GiB
  Current LE             2048
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           254:2

      Processing LV home in VG ncvps-vg.
  --- Logical volume ---
      global/lvdisplay_shows_full_device_path not found in config: defaulting to 0
  LV Path                /dev/ncvps-vg/home
  LV Name                home
  VG Name                ncvps-vg
  LV UUID                ybMqWA-0qcM-f6NI-oN7v-Ven9-fA3B-RSqtIn
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ncvps, 2018-12-13 23:51:02 +0100
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                4.00 GiB
  Current LE             1024
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           254:3

      Processing LV data in VG ncvps-vg.
  --- Logical volume ---
      global/lvdisplay_shows_full_device_path not found in config: defaulting to 0
  LV Path                /dev/ncvps-vg/data
  LV Name                data
  VG Name                ncvps-vg
  LV UUID                TLqETm-cmUW-H40L-fUYr-evmF-VUDW-hLqIha
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ncvps, 2018-12-14 22:25:15 +0100
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                50.00 GiB
  Current LE             12800
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           254:4

  --- Physical volumes ---
  PV Name               /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt     
  PV UUID               XOvj5D-ClTq-gfsw-F59L-aIqN-1tdt-OMGYrI
  PV Status             NOT allocatable
  Total PE / Free PE    191937 / 168913

      Unlocking /run/lock/lvm/V_ncvps-vg
      Setting global/notify_dbus to 1
```

Comment: One clue can be found in: `Allocatable NO`. This generally means that at least this physical volume will not accept extent allocation, regardless of what is available. The reason for this can probably be found via the `vgdisplay` and `lvdisplay` commands.

Answer (score 1):

So as you can see the pysical volume was not allocatable:

```
  PV Status             NOT allocatable
```

with a simple:

```
pvchange -x y /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt
```

it can be made allocatable again.

I have no idea how it became like this, maybe someone can comment how this happens normally.